# Add spacing between image and text in navbar - bootstrap

Tags: html, web, bootstrap-5

[image: Current site]
I have this site at the moment with this code:

```html
<body>
    <nav class="navbar bg-primary">
        <div class="container-inline navbar-brand">
            <img src="img/logo.png"width="55">
            <a class="text-light">Test</a>
        </div>

        <a class="nav-link text-light">One</a>
        <a class="nav-link text-light">Two</a>
        <a class="nav-link text-light">Three</a>
        <a class="nav-link text-light">Four</a>
    </nav>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
```

I want there to be some more spacing between the text "Test" and the logo image, I have tried this such as `ml-3` and `pl-3` and similar, however none of those seem to be working.,

Comment: I am using bootsrtap 5 my bad how would I do this in bootstrap 5?

Answer (score 2):

Apply style with margin property to your img element, u can adjust the pixel

```
<img src="img/logo.png" width="55" style="margin-right:20px">
```

Comment: Oh right, can it not be done with bootstrap? This is where mots of my confusion comes with bootstrap, where I can use bootstrap and where cant I

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin property and padding property of image and make sure to confirm the margin or padding when the display size changes . I think you`re trying to make responsive as well so margin of px doesn`t change with display size . you`re using bootstrap  right.

```
class="navbar-brand"
```

Add class to your image this will give you right margin .

Answer (score 0):

On the div for the image you could add a mr-5

```
<div class="container-inline navbar-brand mr-5">
        <img src="img/logo.png"width="55">
        <a class="text-light">Test</a>
    </div>
```

If you don't need too much space that should work.
mr ranges from 1-5 so adjust as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no longer `ml-*` in Bootstrap 5. It's been replaced with `ms-*`. Read about the [changes from Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/).

```
<div class="container-inline navbar-brand">
    <img src=".." width="55">
    <a class="text-light d-inline-block ms-3">Test</a>
</div>
```

[Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/45uO8Dyiui)

Comment: I just noticed im using bootstrap 5, sorry how would this be done in bootstrap 5?

Comment: Please mark the answer "accepted" so others know the question is solved!